# How can I use the most specialized type of two objects as return type?

Tags: java, generics

What I basically want is, that the more specialized type is inferred like in the following example:

```
Predicate<Object> first;
Predicate<String> second;

Predicate<String> firstOr = first.or(second);
Predicate<String> secondOr = second.or(first);
```

How would the method signature of `or(...)` look like to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be accomplished with the following declaration of `Predicate<T>::or`:

```
default <R extends T> Predicate<R> or(Predicate<? super R> other) {
    return r -> this.test(r) || other.test(r);
}
```

This would allow `or` to create a `Predicate` for any subtype of both `Predicate` types.  So, for example, the following would work:

```
Predicate<Object> first;
Predicate<Number> second;

Predicate<Integer> firstOr = first.or(second);
Predicate<Integer> secondOr = second.or(first);
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I'm getting a compile error on `first.or(second)` saying "Predicate<String> is not compatible with Pred<? super Object>".

Comment: Is it possible that you made class `Pred` to test this and then mixed up `Predicate` and `Pred` ?

Comment: I mixed up Predicate and Pred when I manually wrote the error message. It should have been "Predicate<String> is not compatible with Predicate<? super Object>".

Comment: Ah, I see my error now. I managed to put `? super T` instead of `? super R`. Nice answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you need two overloads for this to work. However, because the only difference between the overloads is in the type parameters, they would clash because of erasure. You therefore need to name them differently (which would not make them actual overloads anymore).

This could be the signatures:

```
/* In this case, the input Predicate has the most specific type.
 * Use this in the first.or(second) case
 */
public <R extends T> Predicate<R> or1(Predicate<R> pred);

/* In this case, the receiver Predicate has the most specific type.
 * Use this in the second.or(first) case
 */
public Predicate<T> or2(Predicate<? super T> pred);
```

Both methods would work the same if the type parameters are equal (for example if both `first` and `second` had the type `Predicate<String>`)

Comment: Not exactly satisfying, but I guess thats Javas fault and not yours :P

Thanks for your help!